# Initialising darknet opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, darknet

I get this error when trying to initialize darknet.

> Error: Assertion failed (separator_index < line.size()) in cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream, file c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp, line 507

Anyone know what may be happening?

I'm using `yolov3.weights` and `yolov3.cfg`

piece of code below.

I've tried absolute file paths

```
// Load names of classes
string classesFile = "B:/coco.names";
ifstream ifs(classesFile.c_str());
string line;
while (getline(ifs, line)) classes.push_back(line);

// Give the configuration and weight files for the model
String modelConfiguration = "B:/yolov3a.cfg";
String modelWeights = "B:/yolov3.weights";

// Load the network
Net net = readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights);
net.setPreferableBackend(DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV);
net.setPreferableTarget(DNN_TARGET_CPU);


//---------------

return 0;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just check up carefully your .cfg file. You may be uncommented inadvertently some comment, like #Testing or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Line parser in darknet_io.cpp seems to fail if there are commented lines without whitespace immidiately after the '#' in the .cfg file.

```
[net]
# This is OK!
# Testing
# batch=1
# subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=416
height=416
...

[net]
#This would FAIL!
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
#Training
batch=64
...
```